# Nginx reverse proxy problem on an specified location

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I wanted to access one of the react projects as the following instruction.

```
https://my.domain.com/app1  ==>  HTTP://localhost:7001
```

The following is the Nginx config:

```
server {
 listen 80;
server_name my.domain.com;
 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
 listen 443 ssl;

 ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;
 ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
 server_name my.domain.com;

 error_log /var/log/nginx/my.domain.com.err;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/my.domain.com.log;

location /app1 {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   add_header Pragma "no-cache";
   add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";

   proxy_pass http://localhost:7001/;
   proxy_redirect default;

   sub_filter_types *;
   sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/app1/';
   sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/app1/';
   sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/app1/';
   sub_filter_once off;
 }
}
```

The problem is that some of the source files responded by `https://my.domain.com/app1/...` but some responded by `https://my.domain.com/...`, there for the second one is not accessible and gives `HTTP 404` error.

For example, the following sources have been responded as `HTTP 200`:

```
https://my.domain.com/app1/static/css/main.091g2s3f.chunk.css
https://my.domain.com/app1/static/js/2.29c551h6.chunk.js
```

And the following is responded as `HTTP 404`:

```
https://my.domain.com/media/contact-title.png
https://my.domain.com/static/media/Yekan.05744gh2.woff
https://my.domain.com/logo.svg
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

---

What I did and not solved:
I did configure the Nginx `rewrite`, simple `proxy_pass` and `regex` but the problem not solved, in addition, I got all the responses as `HTTP 404`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only forwarding /app1 to upstream, if u want to forward media and static etc, then you need to change the following

```
   location /app1
```

to

```
   location /
```

OR if you are serving them as static files, add the following

```
 location /static {
    root  /path/to/your/static/path;
  }
```

then you can call all your static files from example.com/static/something.css

Comment: I don't want to use `/` for this project. I need to access this project in `.../app1`.

Comment: then change your media etc to /app1/media

Comment: Actually, the thing that I was looking for is that handling it without charging media or root API.